# How best to structure and build Clojure apps with plugins?

Tags: plugins, clojure, gradle, leiningen

I think (see below) that I would like to structure a Clojure project as multiple modules, with ordered dependencies - just like Maven lets me do with [multi-modules projects](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects).

But I can't see how to do this with Leiningen - all I can see is the `checkouts` fix described in the [FAQ](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) which doesn't seem to be as powerful.

Will lein do this?  Should I be using Gradle instead?  Or is this kind of thing not needed?

Some more context: I am wondering how to architect a modular application that supports plugins (which I imagine means jars dumped on the classpath).  And am wondering to what extent I can structure that as a core + plugins (I am thinking I should be able to do something with Clojure's [dynamic code loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810231/defining-a-spi-in-clojure) and not have to go with Java/OSGi).  So I guess the driving motivation for a *single* project comes from wanting some way of packaging everything (the core + default plugins) as a single blob that is easy for the end user, but which can also be divided up (and which is built and tested in fragments, testing the logical independence of each module).  More general advice about this is welcome

**Update**

A possible solution that wasn't mentioned below is using a [Maven plugin](https://github.com/talios/clojure-maven-plugin) - I assume that supports everything Maven does, but compiles Clojure, so will work with nested modules, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, it does not seem like Leiningen supports a module hierarchy like Maven does.  The checkouts are the next closest thing it has.  It should be sufficient though to develop a modular application in Clojure though.

For the project structure, I would have an API project, a "core" project, the plugins themselves, and a separate packaging project. The core and the plugins should only depend on the API.  Which build tool you use to create the packaging project is up to you.  Gradle would probably be more effective at handling the packaging, however having the "checkout" functionality Leiningen offers could make development of the system as a whole easier.

I would take a look at the code for Leiningen and Noir to figure out how to effectively handle this.

For dynamically loading the plugins, I would start with looking how Noir handles it in two of their files:

- [server.clj](https://github.com/ibdknox/noir/blob/master/src/noir/server.clj) has namespace loading for all files under a particular namespace.  Under the hood it uses [tools.namespace](https://github.com/clojure/tools.namespace/), but you can easily see how it's used to `require` every namespace under  a particular base.  This is how Leiningen handles custom tasks as well - the base definition for the task should be in the leiningen.$task namespace.
- [core.clj](https://github.com/ibdknox/noir/blob/master/src/noir/core.clj) has what I would use for plugin registration.  In summary, use a map under an `atom` and add plugins to that map.  I would advice wrapping the registration with a macro to keep your code cleaner.

What I listed above should be sufficient if you don't need to handle adding plugins at run time.  If you don't have every plugin on the classpath during start-up, I would recommend utilizing [pomegranite](https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate) to add entries to the classpath.  You can see an example in [classpath.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/leiningen-core/src/leiningen/core/classpath.clj).

Comment: Updated: It seems that Leiningen now supports module hierarchy... according to [lein-modules](https://github.com/jcrossley3/lein-modules) plugin description.