# Clojure hot code swapping for uberjars/.classes

Tags: clojure, osgi

I want to have hot code swapping between project updates, but I haven't found any information about how to load .class files dynamically.
More specifically, I want something like that:

1. Make `lein uberjar`, obtain `some-client-0.0.0-standalone.jar`.
2. Run it with `java -jar some-client-0.0.0-standalone.jar`.
3. Make changes to project. Obtain new program version, `some-client-0.0.1-standalone.jar`, copy it to `some-client-0.0.0-standalone.jar` directory.
4. Client receive sequence of commands needed to update to new version.
5. (optional) Updates resources. Resources from old jar are no longer used.
6. (optional) `some-client-0.0.0-standalone.jar` can be deleted now.

Comment: I think it will be **much** easier to restart client. Why can't you just restart it?

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov If it was about loading code while developing, I would hot-load sources or restart. But I wish to get something like erlang hot code swapping for client application. And yes, I know that it's not that good and can easily crash my program, but it's something I want to try.

Answer (score 6):

**Plug-in framework approach**

You've stated you want to have hot code swapping, but what you actually need is loosely coupled modules and ability to do resolve in run-time. Frankly speaking any plug-in framework may help, including mature OSGi (will be covered below).

[image]

Since you are doing some kind of PoC I suggest to review the following example:

1. you have a meta application with some extension points ([metaphor explanation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_are_extensions_and_extension_points?)) defined
2. functionality to be upgraded or replaced will be implemented as a loosely coupled modules (plug-ins)
3. meta application performs resolve by request or automatically in order to find updated "functionality" (according to defined extension points)

Having that define simlle upgrade scenario can be proposed:

1. user uses an application
2. user installs (copies) a JAR (other type of bundle) with new implementation of one or several extension points
3. user triggers global system resolve or system scans for new updates or system performs resolve every tine user tries to access some piece of functionality

In such a way meta application will be able to provide a new or updated functionality without restart. So you can:

1. try use some simple java plug-in framework (like, for example, [Java Simple Plugin Framework. 5 minutes and it works. No XML.](https://code.google.com/p/jspf/) This approach seems to be a little bit ugly
2. use dynamic nature of clojure, as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810231/defining-a-spi-in-clojure)

You can also review and adopt Waterfront (Clojure based editor for Clojure) findings (it might be needed to enhance lifecycle management, etc)

- check the [Modular composition/plugin architecture](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/clojure/irCGydnCNdA) thread
- look through the code [waterfront on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/waterfront/)

> In terms of implementation, Waterfront is based on the context
>   pattern. It allows event handlers to communicate in a functional
>   (side-effect free) manner. On top of this there is a plugin-loader
>   mechanism which loads the plugins that are specified in Waterfront's
>   configuration file. This means that functionality can be easily added
>   or removed (extremely useful when debugging!).

**OSGI approach**

As was suggested OSGi seems to be a good way to solve your problem. Please also note OSGi is good, mature and provides a lot stuff out of the box, but it is also somewhat complex:

[image]

BTW, OSGi is a long-term goal for the clojure community. You can check [Clojure Todo](http://clojure.org/todo):

```
> better modularization for OSGi etc 
>  * names
>  * no single namespace pool
>  * namespaces found via classes, thus tracks classloader and modules 
>  * deal with import proxying a la Class.forName stack walk?
```

There are some solutions already available:

1. [clojure-osgi-utils](https://github.com/pmoriarty/clojure-osgi-utils)
2. [clojure.osgi](https://github.com/aav/clojure.osgi)

Second project provides Producer-Consumer example using clojure and OSGi:

- [producer service](https://github.com/aav/clojure.osgi/blob/master/clojure.osgi.example.service.producer/src/clojure/osgi/example/service/producer/service_producer.clj)
- [consumer service](https://github.com/aav/clojure.osgi/blob/master/clojure.osgi.example.service.consumer/src/clojure/osgi/example/service/consumer/service_consumer.clj)

Happy coding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810231/defining-a-spi-in-clojure -- I've tried (while true (Thread/sleep 5000) (load "/class_that_changes") (println (eval 'class_that_changes/hello)) (eval '(chass_that_changes/hello))). It reloads .clj, but don't reload .class files. class_that_changes/hello points to same object. Am I doing it wrong?
jspf -- Can be an option, but that requires to write things in Java. Java interop option is still an option, though.

Comment: And clojure.osgi isn't lein project, and that makes me sad.

Comment: waterfront uses load-file, which "Sequentially read and evaluate the set of forms contained in the file". ``.clj``, again, not ``.class``.

Answer (score 2):

For reloading at runtime strictly from jar files you may need to look into [OSGi class loaders](http://blog.osgi.org/2011/05/what-you-should-know-about-class.html).
For Clojure code you could start nrepl in your client that listens on a local port and then when you want to reload the code you connect to that port and make a call to `load-file`

Comment: I'll try that one. Successful examples using it in clojure may help.