# Clojure - require several versions of a library in a project

Tags: clojure

Everything is in the title, but here is an example use case :

a function had a first parameter like the following :

```
(my-fn "a.b.c" ...)
```

Which now in a newer version became :

```
(my-fn ... ["a", "b", "c"])
```

Is it possible to `:require` a specific version of a library ?
For instance :

```
:require my.util.lib :as newlib     ;; new version
:require my.util.lib@v0.0.1 :as lib ;; old library
```

It would then allow to migrate this library usage file per file.

Comment: Loading multiple versions of the same library on JVM is hard. Maybe look at Osgi -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145721/clojure-hot-code-swapping-for-uberjars-classes .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I think `Osgi` is the only true way to accomplish this, and probably not worth the effort in complexity to set it up.

What are the versions of the library you are using? If it is following semantic versioning practices, and it still on a version with breaking changes, you have to be prepared for this sort of thing and will probably just have to update your code.